# Differences in Image handling in Magento2 and Magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, magento2.2

I have upgraded Magento from 1.9.2.2 to 2.2.1. 
I have migrated data using [data migration tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool).
I have observed that for products for those images are marked excluded are appearing as hidden in Magento2 but in Magento1 which is marked as excluded still appearing on frontend as product base image and thumbnail as it is marked so.

For example, I have a product ABC and it has two images i1 and i2, both are marked as excluded but i2 is selected as base, small and thumbnail.
Now after migration in Magento2 both the images are hidden, which is correct and i2 is also showing correct tags like i2 is marked as small, base and thumbnail but it is not appearing on frontend. 

What is the difference between two Magento versions in handling and processing images?

Answer (score 0):

Edit :
found answer here. Could help some others :
https://www.ubertheme.com/question/all-product-images-set-to-hidden/

> Hi there, That because your images has marked to excluded in back-end
>   of your site. If you want to enable with mass images, you can run
>   bellow sql:

```
> Update `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` set `disabled` = 0;
> Update `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` set `disabled` =
> 0;
```

And clean the Magento2 cache. And tell me know how it goes.